# Stop Winform keystroke from reaching child control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that has several buttons. I have KeyPreview set to true, and I have `Keydown`, `KeyPress`, and keyup events all reading

```
form_keyevent(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.handled = true;
}
```

For some reason, the enter key still clicks a button that has focus. What am I missing? Is there a way around it?

Comment: Is your button set to be the "accept" button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing the Enter key on a `Form` with a focused button invokes the [`Form.ProcessCmdKey` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method is called during message preprocessing to handle command keys. *Command keys are keys that always take precedence over regular input keys.* Examples of command keys include accelerators and menu shortcuts.

You can override this method to mark the key as handled:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    // if enter pressed, return 'true' to skip default handler
    if ((keyData & Keys.Return) == Keys.Return)
        return true;

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

If you only want to ignore Enter when buttons are focused, you can use something like:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    // if a button is focused AND enter pressed, skip default handler
    if (this.ActiveControl is Button && (keyData & Keys.Return) == Keys.Return)
        return true;

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Very informative and thorough. I had no idea Forms treated command keys differently. Very useful to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This could be happening if your button is set as the `AcceptButton` property on the form.  If that is the case, just clear that property.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers You can add a [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler to your form, in its [`KeyEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs(v=vs.110).aspx) there is a [`SuppressKeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress(v=vs.110).aspx) property which will prevent your Keypress from being sent to the parent control.

also see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557442/keyeventargs-handled-vs-keyeventargs-supresskeypress) for what the differences are between handled and SuppressKeyPress,

From the SuppressKeyPress Link:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the key event should be passed on to the underlying control.

example:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode  == Keys.Enter )
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Comment: A keyboard shortcut inside Form1_KeyDown() will stop working when the same shortcut is added to the menu which is then added to Form1_Designer.cs.